# Connection closed before full header was received in flutter app with apollo server as backend

Tags: flutter, typegraphql, graphql-flutter

Created an flutter app with typegraphql and apollo server in backend. Application works fine. But at random times it throws an error,

OperationException(linkException: ServerException(originalException: Connection closed before full header was received, parsedResponse: null), graphqlErrors: [])

Comment: Having the same issue, cannot locate the reason for that :/

Comment: Having the same issue and no one can answer it.

Comment: Even I am facing this random same issue. @Janith:  did you get any solution?